# how to arrange table output ranges in R

Tags: r

I am a beginner in r. I have this script:

```
BMIcate<-character(0)  
BMIcate[adultkidneytx$BMI < 20] <- "< 20"  
BMIcate[adultkidneytx$BMI>= 20 & adultkidneytx$BMI <= 25] <- "20 - 25"  
BMIcate[adultkidneytx$BMI > 25 & adultkidneytx$BMI <=30] <- "25 - 30"  
BMIcate[adultkidneytx$BMI > 30 ] <- ">30"  

table(BMIcate)

table(BMIcate, adultkidneytx$TypeTx)

table.BMIgroup<- table(BMIcate, adultkidneytx$TypeTx)
```

Output table has the categories BMIcate  in this order:

```
"< 20" , ">30" , "20 - 25" , "25 - 30"      

 BMIcate   Deceased donor transplants      Living donor transplants
< 20                           27                      102
>30                            19                      115
20 - 25                         32                      185
25 - 30                         32                      194

 I want BMIcate in order: "< 20", "20-25", "26-30", ">30"
```

Comment: The code is not working (no `adultkidneytx` object), but you may try casting `BMIcate` into `factor` with `levels = c("< 20", "20 - 25", "25 - 30", ">30")`.

Answer (score 0):

you should use the cut function

```
BMI <- cut(adultkidneytx$BMI ,breaks = c(20,25,30) )
```

then change the label if you want